# Web scraping in Stack Overflow with scrapy but I can't get the votes of the question

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping Stack Overflow, I'm catching the title, URL and tags already, but I cannot catch the vote of each question. Can someone help me? I'm not so good with xpath

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    questions = response.xpath('//div[@class="question-summary"]')

    for question in questions:
        item = StackItem()
        item['url'] = question.xpath(
            'div[@class="summary"]/h3/a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
        item['title'] = question.xpath(
            'div[@class="summary"]/h3/a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['tags'] = question.xpath(
            'div[@class="summary"]/div[2]/a[@class="post-tag"]/text()').extract()
        item['votes'] = question.xpath(
            '/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span/strong/textContent()').extract()[0]

        yield item
```

I'm scraping the page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

Comment: `textContent()` is not a valid XPath function. If you need string representation - use `string()`. If you need single text node - `text()`. Try `span[normalize-space(@class)="vote-count-post"]/strong/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
item['votes'] = question.css('.vote-count-post > strong::text').extract()[0]
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use xpath

```
item['votes'] = question.xpath(".//div[@class='votes']//strong/text()").extract_first()
```

note the dot prefixing the .//div xpath
[Check scrapy doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths)